# Como validar caracteres válidos para latitude e longitude durante digitação?

Tags: javascript, regex

Tenho um input de texto para digitação de latitude e outro para longitude.

Eu gostaria que o campo permitisse a digitação somente dos caracteres válidos para latitude e longitude.

Creio o campo deva aceitar apenas números, "." e "-", correto?

Á principio creio que algo com regex dê certo, mas não sei como ficaria a regex:

```
    // Campo para latitude e longitude;
    $(".latitude, .longitude").on('keypress', function (event) {
        var regex = new RegExp(??????);
        var key = String.fromCharCode(!event.charCode ? event.which : event.charCode);
        if (!regex.test(key)) {             
           event.preventDefault();             
           return false;
        }  
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bem basicão mas funcionou...

```
    $("[id*='" + camposSharepoint.Ocorrencias.LatitudeEvento + "'],[id*='" + camposSharepoint.Ocorrencias.LongitudeEvento + "']").on('keypress', function (event) {
        var regex = new RegExp("[0-9\-\,]");
        var key = String.fromCharCode(!event.charCode ? event.which : event.charCode);
        if (!regex.test(key)) {             
           event.preventDefault();             
           return false;
        }  
    });
```

Se alguém conseguir melhorar para que não repita os caracteres "-" e "," ficaria perfeito

Comment: Passe uma lista com exemplos... um [mcve](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) de um Ideone ou algo do tipo... De exemplos de erro, acertos, etc. Ou [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/6m20wt/1)